# Python model pip installed successfully, but no model named?

Tags: python-2.7

I have the model "PyPDF2" installed successfully through pip install as shown below:

[image]

But when I'm using Pycharm to import PyPDF2, there is this error:

[image]

For your information, I only have one version of Python which is Python2.7 installed on my C: drive, and I have my Pycharm installed on my D: drive.
Also, I have my pip the latest version as instructed when I was first-time installing the PyPDF2 package.
Please show me how to deal with the problem, thanks!

Comment: please provide the content of spf.py. Also if you're using a recent version of PyCharm you might be running your code inside a virtualenv. Check the python interpreter used by PyCharm for you project.

Comment: there is no content of spf.py, only this line "import PyPDF2".

Comment: how to check my Pycharm?